# Regular expression to add '.html' to url

Tags: regex, sed, wget

I want to modify some links after doing some scrapping using wget.

During the export of my website using wget, links such as href="http://www.domain.com/whatever/page"
are converted to href="http://www.domain.com/whatever/page.html"

But links that reference outside the scope of wget are not modified, and in some case I would like to do so.

My command is such that href="http://www.domain.com/whatever/page" should become href="http://www.domain.com/whatever/page.html"

My current regulare expression is

```
sed -e "s|\"\(http://www\.domain\.com/.*\)/\([^\./]+\)\"|\"\1/\2.html\"|g"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: do you really need regex for this? can't you just add `.html` to the string?

Comment: This is an automated script that should modify all links which don't have an extension, or a trailing slash at the end, I cannot really see a way to do otherwise

Comment: Here's a working regex to match all hrefs without `.html` at the end. Not posting an answer cause I don't know sed:
`href="(.(?!\.html))*"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ perl -pe 's@href="http://www\.domain\.com/([^/]+/)?\w+(?!\.html)(?=")@$&.html@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e "s|\"\(http://www\.domain\.com/.*\)/\(.\+\)\"|\"\1/\2.html\"|g"
```